# Implementing a custom Iterator Trait

Tags: rust, iterator

Source code

```
pub struct Iterating_ex {
    start: u32,
    end: u32,
}

impl Iterator for Iterating_ex {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if self.start >= self.end {
            None
        } else {
            let result = Some(self.start);
            self.start += 1;
            result
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let example = Iterating_ex {
        start: 0,
        end: 5,
    };
    for i in example {
        println!("{i}");
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Individually I understand what each piece of code is trying to do, however I am having trouble understanding the following, possibly due to my lack of understanding of the generic iterator trait;

1. Does implementing the Iterator trait for a struct automatically generate an iterable data type? In this case, I don't know why a for loop can be used on `example`.
2. It seems like the `next` method is called as a loop until `None` is returned. How does the code know to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ad 1**. To be "iterable" in rust means to implement the `Iterator` trait. Some things however can be *turned* into an iterator and that is described by another trait `IntoIterator`. Standard library provides a blanket implementation:

```rust
impl<I: Iterator> IntoIterator for I { /* ... */}
```

Which means that any type that implements `Iterator` can be turned into one (it's noop). `for` loops are designed to work with types that implement `IntoIterator`. That's why you can write for example:

```rust
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for _ in &v {}
for _ in &mut v {}
for _ in v {}
```

Since types `&Vec<T>`, `&mut Vec<T>` and `Vec<T>` all implement `IntoIterator` trait. They all are turned into different iterator types of course, and are returning respectively `&T`, `&mut T` and `T`.

**Ad 2**. As stated before for loops can be used on types that implement `IntoIterator`. The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator) explains in detail how it works, but in a nutshell `for` loop is just a syntax sugar that turns this code:

```rust
for x in xs {
    todo!()
}
```

Into something like this:

```rust
let mut xs_iter = xs.into_iter();
while let Some(x) = xs_iter.next() {
    todo!()
}
```

`while` loops are also syntax sugar and are de-sugared into `loop` with a `break` statement but that's not relevant here.

**Side note**. I guess that this is just a learning example, and it's great, but the exact same iterator already exists in the standard library as `std::ops::Range`, so use that it your actual code if you need it.